# Having trouble getting Algolia Search to recognize my custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-fields, algolia

I've recently implemented the Algolia Search Wordpress plugin into a new WP build for my client.  The site will essentially be used to collect survey data and provide it's admins a robust search functionality.

I've created a custom post type that will contain a unique post for each survey submission.  Each survey input field is pushed to a custom field within the post.

In the following example, I'm trying to implement Algolia's custom field push and retrieve featured here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/advanced-custom-fields.html#push-custom-fields-to-algolia.  My custom post type is entitled 'Submissions' and I'm trying to push a custom field with a key of 'organisation_name' within that post type.  Again, I think I have everything set correctly, but this custom field is not being indexed by Algolia.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Push custom fields to Algolia
add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_searchable_post_shared_attributes', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );

/**
 * @param array   $attributes
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_post_attributes( array $attributes, WP_Post $post ) {

    if ( 'submissions' !== $post->post_type ) {
        // We only want to add an attribute for the 'submissions' post type.
        // Here the post isn't a 'submission', so we return the attributes unaltered.
        return $attributes;
    }

    // Get the field value with the 'get_field' method and assign it to the attributes array.
    // @see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
    $attributes['organisation_name'] = get_field( 'organisation_name', $post->ID );

    // Always return the value we are filtering.
    return $attributes;
}


// Make custom fields searchable
add_filter( 'algolia_posts_index_settings', 'my_posts_index_settings' );
// We could also have used a more general hook 'algolia_posts_index_settings',
// but in that case we would have needed to add a check on the post type
// to ensure we only adjust settings for the 'speaker' post_type.

/**
 * @param array $settings
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_posts_index_settings( array $settings ) {

    if ( 'submissions' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return $settings;
    }

    // Make Algolia search into the 'bio' field when searching for results.
    // Using ordered instead of unordered would make words matching in the beginning of the attribute
    // make the record score higher.
    // @see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#attributestoindex
    $settings['attributesToIndex'][] = 'unordered(organisation_name)';

    // Make Algolia return a pre-computed snippet of 50 chars as part of the result set.
    // @see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#attributestohighlight
    $settings['attributesToSnippet'][] = 'organisation_name:50';

    // Always return the value we are filtering.
    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm you use the ACF plugin? Also, did you re-index everything after you introduced the filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/advanced-custom-fields.html#push-custom-fields-to-algolia addresses integration with the Advanced Custom Field plugin.

That being said, you could also replace the `get_field` calls with 'get_post_meta' which is native to WordPress.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_searchable_post_shared_attributes', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );

/**
 * @param array   $attributes
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_post_attributes( array $attributes, WP_Post $post ) {



$attributes['_geoloc']['lat'] = (float) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'latitude', true );

$attributes['_geoloc']['lng'] = (float) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'longitude', true );


// Always return the value we are filtering.

return $attributes;
}
```

Here we get 2 meta fields `latitude` & `longitude` out of the post.

Comment: Thank so much for this.  This actually tackles another issue that I may have had in the near future as well, which is including more than one custom field in the $attributes array.

Comment: You are welcome, please note though that in this example I actually added only one entry in the array, which is _geoloc. But you can add as many as you want ;), you are not forced to take the nested array path.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you know how I might add additional attributes to the array?

Comment: Yes, simply replace `$attributes['_geoloc']['lat']` with `$attributes['my_attribute']`. You can add as many as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it!  The problem was that this code was only meant to be used with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (ACF).  The my_post_attributes() function was calling upon a get_field() method which didn't exist in my Wordpress install because my custom fields were not being created by the ACF plugin.  Once, I installed the plugin, the code successfully pushed the custom field to Algolia.

```
// Get the field value with the 'get_field' method and assign it to the attributes array.
// @see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
$attributes['organisation_name'] = get_field( 'organisation_name', $post->ID );
```